# How to Connect VPS via SSH/Putty to FTP and transefer file from FTP to VPS and then delete file

Tags: linux, ftp, vps

I have a vps (virtual private server) and web hosting control panels is Direct Admin and inner of that have wordpress, email and the backup of the each of that save in server, also another backups save to ftp. How can I connect from vps to ftp? ftp backup address is noc.netmihan.com first I connect to server with putty, then I try to connect to ftp I use the bellow command ftp noc.netmihan.com but error -bash ftp command not found

VPS company say cannot see the backup folder through WinSCP and you should connect to FTP from terminal and see backups folder and delete old backups folder and free space. can you please help me to do that? Thanks for your time

[image]

[image]

I need alittle help , First I login successful to FTP, after that type

```
ls -a 
150 Here comes the directory listing
drwxr-xr-x   15 4754     4754         4096 Sep 30 23:43 daily
drwxr-xr-x    3 4754     4754         4096 Jan 26  2023 weekly
```

then i go to folder daily

```
cd  daily
ls

150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 May 18  2023 Apr
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jul 31  2023 Aug
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jan 31 23:44 Feb
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jun 30  2023 Jul
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 May 31  2023 Jun
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 May 18  2023 Mar
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jun 08  2023 May
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Sep 30 23:43 Oct
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Aug 31 23:42 Sep
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Feb 06  2023 week-1
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Mar 09  2023 week-2
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jan 28  2023 week-4
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Feb 05  2023 week-5
```

for example  i want to go to the Jan folder

```
ftp> cd Jan
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode (185,94,97,194,58,98).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> cd ..
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode (185,94,97,194,41,65).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
drwxr-xr-x    2 4754     4754         4096 Jan 28  2023 Jan
```

My question is how can I download this file from FTP  to my vps (directAdmin path?) and then  delete this file?
thanks for your time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `ftp` command is not installed... You can try : `apt install ftp` if you are on a Debian based distribution. Note that `FTP` protocol is not a secured protocol (no encryption).

Comment: thanks a lot. it works

Comment: can you please introduce me command lines for transfer files and then delete files?

Answer (score 0):

Finally according to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749517/ftp-delete-non-empty-directory

```
use the bellow command
mdelete folder_name/*
rmdir folder_name
```